# How do I ScrollIntoView after changing the filter on a ListView in a MVVM (WPF) App?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm, filter

I have an ObservableCollection in the VM that is displayed in the view in a ListView. When the selected item changes, the SelectionChanged event fires nicely. Below is how I have the ListView configured:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="3" Margin="5" AlternationCount="2" Name="_lvSettings" 
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CollectionView}" 
          SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=SelectedSettingIndex}"
          SelectionChanged="OnSelectionChanged"  >
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="170" 
                            Header="{Binding Path=ShowAllDisplay}"
                            x:Name="_colSettings"  
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Setting}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Old Value" Width="150" 
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=OldVal}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="New Value" 
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=NewVal}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

The problem I have is when I change the filter on the collection. The selected item remains the same, which is good, but the ListView changes to display from the first item, and often the selected item is out of view (but still the selected item).

In the VM, I have the property "SelectedSettingIndex" that throws the PropertyChanged event when it changes. Even if I raise the event myself manually (base.OnPropertyChanged("SelectedSettingIndex");) from the VM when the filter changes, the event does not seem to really get raised as the property did not really change. There must be a way to call ScrollIntoView or something similar in this scenario, but I can't figure out the correct event or trigger to do so. What is it that I am missing?

**EDIT**

Here is a, hopefully better, description of the issue I am concerned with:

1) I am using a CollectionViewSource in the VM to filter data.

2) There is a button for the user to toggle between a filter.

3) Lets assume the ListView has room to show up to 10 items at any given time.

4) The user selects item "A" in the filtered view which is at index 50 in the listview.

5) The user then clicks the button to turn filtering off.

Expected Results: The ListView is populated with the unfiltered list, Item "A" remains selected, and the ListView is "scrolled" such that item "A" is still visible.

Actual Results: The ListView is populated with the unfiltered list, Item "A" remains selected, and the ListView is "scrolled" to the top and showing the first 10 items. Item "A" is not in view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the SelectedItem of your ListView in a property:

```
public MyTypeOfObject SelectedItem { get; set; }
```

Assign the binding to XAML:

```
<ListView Name="MyListView" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"...></ListView>
```

Now whenever you change filter do:

```
if (SelectedItem != null)
    MyListView.ScrollIntoView(SelectedItem);
```

**EDIT:**

To do it in your user control, in order to leave you view model clean from control references (ListView), catch a standard `CollectionView` event there or define your own that will be fired after filter or other job happened.

Comment: I am pretty much already doing what you suggest in the first post, except using the SelectedIndex instead of the SelectedItem, and I am not referencing the ListView in my VM. Either way my results are the same - changing the filter resets the view to be "scrolled" to the beginning.

For your second suggestion - I am using a CollectionView (in the VM) to do the filtering. I could not find an appropriate event to respond to, or how to respond to one from the view. Can you provide more detail?

Comment: Oops - not entirely true what I said - I am using a ListCollectionView to do the sorting. Not certain that makes a difference...

Comment: @KJ Before applying the filter keeping the SelectedItem to a temp variable and set it again afterwards. In order this to take effect in your ListView you have to use OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem") to nofity UI for the manual property change. Consider that you previous SelectedItem is not in your view anymore because of filter. In that case do CollectionView.MoveCurrentToFirst().

Comment: The selected item is the correct selected item after the filter change. That is not an issue. Calling OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem") does nothing since the value for the seleceted item has (correctly) not changed.

Answer (score 13):

If you are using MVVM then you need to make sure that you have set the binding to the selected item in viewModel and that too with `Mode=TwoWay` ... and for scrolling on Selection we have to use a behavior on ListView(avoiding code behind)

You have to add a reference to    `System.Windows.Interactivity` to use `Behavior<T> class`

## Behavior

```
public class ScrollIntoViewForListView : Behavior<ListView>
{
    /// <summary>
    ///  When Beahvior is attached
    /// </summary>
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        this.AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged += AssociatedObject_SelectionChanged;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// On Selection Changed
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    void AssociatedObject_SelectionChanged(object sender,
                                           SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is ListView)
        {
            ListView listview = (sender as ListView);
            if (listview.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                listview.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                    (Action) (() =>
                                  {
                                      listview.UpdateLayout();
                                      if (listview.SelectedItem !=
                                          null)
                                          listview.ScrollIntoView(
                                              listview.SelectedItem);
                                  }));
            }
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// When behavior is detached
    /// </summary>
    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        this.AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged -=
            AssociatedObject_SelectionChanged;

    }
}
```

## Usage

Add alias to `XAML` as  `xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"`

then in your `Control`
    
                
                    
                
        
            
                
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Setting}"/>

Now When ever "MySelectedItem" property is set in `ViewModel` the List will be scrolled when changes are refelected.

## Change Notification

In viewModel should invoke INotifyProperty changed in the setter of properties that you have binded to your xaml so that changes in viewModel can be refelected to View ...

## Using SelectionChanged Event in MVVM

Also in MVVM you dant have to use the "SelectionChnaged Event" as you can call a function in the Setter of  MySelectedItem property or you can use `EventToCommand` class for explicit Event call..

## Filtering

Google usage of ColletionViewSource for features like sorting ,filtering..etc

Hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks for the post - this is very interesting. I think I did a poor job of stating the problem, however. "Scrolling on selection" is working fine in my code. Please see my edit above for what is hopefully a better description. Also - I did try the "Two-way" binding, but it makes no difference since selection changes were already working fine. What I need to respond to is the change of filter and the re-population of the ListView to get the current selection (which is still correctly selected) back into view.

Answer (score 1):

OK - so I found 2 solutions that work, but not 100% satisfied with:

1) Use the Mediator pattern for the ViewModel to notify the view that the filter has changed. The view then will call ScrollToView on the currently selected item. While I like the Mediator for VM to VM notification, it somehow feels dirty to use it between the ViewModel and its matching View.

2) Call ScrollToView on the currently selected item inside the handler to the ListView's LayoutUpdated event. Heavy-handed, inefficient - just plain don't like this.

I am not going to mark this answered in hopes of a better solution. Just putting this here for the curious or others who may be looking at a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution from some other posts [(Credit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18019425/scrollintoview-for-wpf-datagrid-mvvm), bind an attached property to the count of the collectionview filter:

Attached Property:

```
public class SelectingItemAttachedProperty
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectingItemProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "SelectingItem",
        typeof(int),
        typeof(SelectingItemAttachedProperty),
        new PropertyMetadata(default(int), OnSelectingItemChanged));

    public static int GetSelectingItem(DependencyObject target)
    {
        return (int)target.GetValue(SelectingItemProperty);
    }

    public static void SetSelectingItem(DependencyObject target, int value)
    {
        target.SetValue(SelectingItemProperty, value);
    }

    static void OnSelectingItemChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var lb = sender as ListBox;
        if (lb?.SelectedItem == null)
            return;

        lb.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
        {
            lb.UpdateLayout();
            lb.ScrollIntoView(lb.SelectedItem);
        });
    }
}
```

View:

```
<Listbox
    design:SelectingItemAttachedProperty.SelectingItem="{Binding CollectionViewFromVM.Count}"
   ...>
```

This seems to work fine for most cases =)

Comment: ICollectionView has an event CollectionChanged which gets fired when filters change. You can hook into that in the code behind and scroll to the SelectedItem of the ListView control.