# ScrollIntoView for WPF DataGrid (MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, scroll

I'm using the MVVM pattern, and I've created a binding in XAML for the SelectedItem of a DataGrid. I programatically set the SelectedItem, however when I do so the DataGrid does not scroll to the selection. Is there any way  I can achieve this without completely breaking the MVVM pattern?

I found the following solution but I get an error when I try to implement the `Behavior` class, even though I've installed Blend SDK: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/125583/ScrollIntoView-for-a-DataGrid-when-using-MVVM

Comment: What error do you get when trying to implement the `Behavior`?

Comment: @Gjeltema `The type or namespace name 'Behavior' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Do you have a reference to System.Windows.Interactivity.dll in your project?

Comment: @Gjeltema I can't see one. Will adding one mean that I have to ship yet another DLL with my program though?

Comment: If you're wanting to utilize `Behavior`s (which you'll need for this feature that you're working on, as well as other things), then yes, you'll need to add this dll.  This dll should be present in the Blend SDK and should have been registered when you installed it.

Comment: @Gjeltema I've found the DLL and added a reference to it in my project and the errors have gone now. But is there really now other way to achieve this 'functionality'? Also, I assume it's ok to use the DLL in my commercial application without having to include any additional licenses?

Comment: It's a `System` dll, so no, you won't have to include any additional licenses.  And yes, you can implement `Behavior` like... uh behavior by using attached properties.  Blend `Behavior`s just give you more power.

Comment: @Gjeltema Would you be able to provide an answer that uses attached properties to do the same thing so that I don't have to reference the DLL then please?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This should work.  The idea is you have this attached property that you will attach to the `DataGrid`.  In the xaml where you attach it, you'll bind it to a property on your `ViewModel`.  Whenever you want to programmatically assign a value to the `SelectedItem`, you also set a value to this property, which the attached property is bound to.

I've made the attached property type to be whatever the `SelectedItem` type is, but honestly it doesn't matter what the type is as long as you set it to something different than what it was before.  This attached property is just being used as a means to execute some code on the view control (in this case, a `DataGrid`) in an MVVM friendly fashion.

So, that said, here's the code for the attached property:

```
namespace MyAttachedProperties
{
    public class SelectingItemAttachedProperty
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectingItemProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "SelectingItem",
            typeof(MySelectionType),
            typeof(SelectingItemAttachedProperty),
            new PropertyMetadata(default(MySelectionType), OnSelectingItemChanged));

        public static MySelectionType GetSelectingItem(DependencyObject target)
        {
            return (MySelectionType)target.GetValue(SelectingItemProperty);
        }

        public static void SetSelectingItem(DependencyObject target, MySelectionType value)
        {
            target.SetValue(SelectingItemProperty, value);
        }

        static void OnSelectingItemChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var grid = sender as DataGrid;
            if (grid == null || grid.SelectedItem == null)
                return;

            // Works with .Net 4.5
            grid.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => 
            {
                grid.UpdateLayout();
                grid.ScrollIntoView(grid.SelectedItem, null);
            });

            // Works with .Net 4.0
            grid.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                grid.UpdateLayout();
                grid.ScrollIntoView(grid.SelectedItem, null);
            }));
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the xaml snippet:

```
<Window ...
        xmlns:attachedProperties="clr-namespace:MyAttachedProperties">
    ...
        <DataGrid 
            attachedProperties:SelectingItemAttachedProperty.SelectingItem="{Binding MyViewModel.SelectingItem}">
            ...
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: +1 Thank you very much for your answer. However I get the following error: `System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher' does not contain a definition for 'InvokeAsync' and no extension method 'InvokeAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`. Any ideas why? I've changed `MySelectionType`

Comment: @Andy Apologies, I'm still working in .Net 4.5.  I'll update my answer to reflect .Net 4.0.

Comment: oh ok haha, that's alright! It's working perfectly now - one less DLL! Wish I could upvote your answer again!

Comment: @Andy Glad to have helped!

Comment: I extended this using templates (ScrollIntoViewAttachedProperty<TItem>) and then create concrete dependency properties for differing types by declaring a 'one line class' (public class SelectedLogEntryAttachedProperty : ScrollIntoViewAttachedProperty<SCPLogEntry> { }) so it can be referenced in the XAML. Does someone know how to reference a generic type in XAML to avoid having to create this 'one line class'?

Comment: @Gjeltema sorry to be so dim but what is 'MySelectionType'? thanks

Comment: @AndrewSimpson Sorry for the delay, just noticed this. `MySelectionType` is merely the type of the property that you will bind this attached property to.  So, for example, say you bind this behavior to a property on your view model declared like so: `public IFooViewModel SelectingItem { get; }` (see the example I have in the xaml snippet that shows the binding to SelectingItem). In this case, replace `MySelectionType` in the attached behavior with `IFooViewModel`. Make sense?

Comment: @Gjeltema Thanks for the clarification. :)

Comment: Sorry for being late to the party, but calling `UpdateLayout()` is probably unnecessary - my grid (even when compiled against .NET 4.5.2 & XAML 2006) scrolled just fine _without_ any call to that method, i. e. only called `grid.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => grid.ScrollIntoView(grid.SelectedItem));`

Answer (score 23):

I am new to MVVM. I understand the idea of MVVM and try to implement everything correctly. 
I had a similar problem to above and I ended up with 1 line in XAML and 1 line in code behind. The rest of the code is in the VM.
I did the following in XAML

```
<ListBox DockPanel.Dock="Top"
    Name="Selection1List" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedList1ItemsSource}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedList1Item}"
    SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedList1SelectedIndex}"
    SelectionChanged="Selection1List_SelectionChanged">
```

And this in the code behind:

```
private void Selection1List_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
    Selection1List.ScrollIntoView(Selection1List.SelectedItem);
}
```

and this works fine.

I know some people don't want even one line of code in the code behind the window. But I think this 1 line is just for the view. It has nothing to do with the data or with the logic of the data. So I would think this is no violation of the MVVM principle - and so much easier to implement.

Any comments are welcome.

Comment: Excellent answer. I would suggest an extra null check on the SelectedItem before using `ScrollIntoView` as the code would throw a NullReferenceException upon removing an item from the ItemsSource and not having any selected item.

Comment: I do suggest to use the sender like this: `if (sender is DataGrid dataGrid && dataGrid.SelectedItem != null)  dataGrid.ScrollIntoView(dataGrid.SelectedItem);`

Comment: I like this answer. Since this is GUI-related, I am ok with code-behind :)

Answer (score 1):

The solution of @Edgar works fine, but in my application I had to check the OriginalSource of the SelectionChangedEventArgs as well.

```
private void OperatorQualificationsTable_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((OperatorQualificationsTable.SelectedItem != null) && (e.OriginalSource?.Equals(OperatorQualificationsTable) ?? false))
    {
        OperatorQualificationsTable.ScrollIntoView(OperatorQualificationsTable.SelectedItem);
    }
}
```

My datagrid contains following ComboBoxColumn

```
<dgx:EnhancedDataGridComboBoxColumn 
    DisplayMemberPath="DescriptionNL"
    Header="{x:Static nl:Strings.Label_Qualification}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=QualificationKeysView, Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}"
    SelectedValueBinding="{Binding ActivityQualification.QualificationKey}"
    SelectedValuePath="QualificationKey"/>
```

Everytime when I scrolled up or down the selction changed event was called for the Combobox and it was no longer possible to move the selected item out of the view.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution to get `ScrollIntoView` working. I perform the operation in the `LayoutUpdated()` event

```
public void ManipulateData()
{
    // Add a new record or what else is needed;
    myItemsSourceCollection.Add(...); 

    // Not needed when the ItemsSource is a ObervableCollectin 
    // with correct Binding (ItemsSource="{ Binding myItemsSourceElement }")
    myDataGrid.Items.Refresh();

    // Goto last Item or where ever
    myDataGrid.SelectedIndex = this.myDataGrid.Items.Count - 1;
}

// The LayoutUpdated event for the DataGrid
private void myDataGrid_LayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (myDataGrid.SelectedItem == null)
        return;
    //<----------

    // may become improved to check first if the `ScrollIntoView()` is really needed

    // To prevent hanging here the ItemsSource must be 
    // a) an ObervableCollection with a correct working binding or
    // b) myDataGrid.Items.Refresh(); must be called after changing
    // the data
    myDataGrid.ScrollIntoView(myDataGrid.SelectedItem, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

```
public class ScrollingDataGrid : DataGrid
{
    protected override void OnSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var grid = e.Source as DataGrid;

        if(grid.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            grid.UpdateLayout();
            grid.ScrollIntoView(grid.SelectedItem, null);
        }

        base.OnSelectionChanged(e);
    }
}
```