# Keep scroll position with virtualized datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I've a little problem. I have a datagrid, which display lots of rows. So, for improve performance, I've decided to virtualize my datagrid. 
Until this, no problem. Now, I would like to keep the scroll position after refresh.

In spite of some research, I don't find the solution.
This is my code now, but, it doesn't work :

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="Test" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemCollection}" SelectionMode="Single"  IsReadOnly="True"
                         CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False"
                         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
                         VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True" VirtualizingPanel.IsContainerVirtualizable="True"
                         VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" Grid.Row="1"
                         ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
```

In my ViewModel, I refresh my datagrid like this :

```
public ICollectionView ItemCollection
{
    get
    {
        return _itemCollection;
    }
    set
    {
        _itemCollection= value;
        OnPropertyChanged(() => ItemCollection);
    }
}
```

And this is my function that refesh the datagrid collection :

```
var orderCollection = Items.OrderByDescending(item => item.BeginDate);

var itemCollection = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(orderCollection);
itemCollection.GroupDescriptions.Clear();

using (itemCollection.DeferRefresh())
{
    itemCollection.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("ShortStartDate"));
    itemCollection.Filter = ApplyFilter;
}

ItemCollection = itemCollection;
```

And this, my code behind. The GetScrollPosition is called just before the call of the method above. And the SetScrollPosition is call just after.

```
private void GetScrollPosition()
{
    if (DayBooks != null)
    {
        var scrollViewer = GetScrollViewer(DayBooks);
        if (scrollViewer != null)
            _currentScrollPosition = scrollViewer.VerticalOffset;
    }
}

public void SetScrollPosition()
{
    if (Test != null)
    {
        var scrollViewer = GetScrollViewer(Test);
        if (scrollViewer != null)
        {
            if (_currentScrollPosition != 0)
            {
                scrollViewer.InvalidateScrollInfo();
                scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(_currentScrollPosition);
            }
        }
    }
}

private ScrollViewer GetScrollViewer(UIElement element)
{
    if (element == null) return null;

    ScrollViewer retour = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(element) && retour == null; i++)
    {
        if (VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(element, i) is ScrollViewer)
        {
            retour = (ScrollViewer)(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(element, i));
        }
        else
        {
            retour = GetScrollViewer(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(element, i) as UIElement);
        }
    }
    return retour;
}
```

So, when my datagrid is updated, I tried to set my scroll position (_currentScrollPosition), but the position stay to 0 and I lost my position.

Does it possible to solve my problem and keep my virtualization process ?

Comment: I've edit my question... This line, scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(_currentScrollPosition); have no effect on my datagrid ! After resfresh, my datagrid scroll position stay to 0 and ans lost my position after the refresh

Comment: How do you "refresh" the DataGrid? This part is missing from your question.

Comment: Question is updated again. Sorry ;)

Comment: Where and when is the GetScrollViewer actually being called? You should read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I edited my post again. Hope my question is ok

Answer (score 0):

Your sort of problem is usally solved with a scroll into view behavior that reacts upon a selecteditem instead of a certain scoll position:
[ScrollIntoView for WPF DataGrid (MVVM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18019425/scrollintoview-for-wpf-datagrid-mvvm#18028873)

Did you consider using such a behavior to implement the behavior you are looking for?

Comment: The ScrollIntoView method works. But the problem, the user have to click in order to keep the position in the datagrid. They prefered just scroll and if the datagrid is refresh, keep their position !

Comment: But, I will try to make the same things with the ScrollToVerticalOffset method and a behaviour. Maybe...