# Set Focus to Row in datagrid - WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I've implemented a search command into my MVVM application.

When the selected row in the datagrid get's updated. 
The issue is that the focus for this row does not update.

The data grid will also not scroll too the Row.

**Method**

```
private void Search(string userNameToSearch)
{
var SearchedUser = Users.FirstOrDefault(user => user.UserName == 
userNameToSearch.ToLower());
        if (SearchedUser == null)
            MessageBox_Show(null, "User Not Found", "Search");

SelectedUser = SearchedUser;
}
```

**Command**

```
RelayCommand _searchCommand;

    public ICommand SearchCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_searchCommand == null)
            {
                _searchCommand = new RelayCommand(param => Search((string)param));
            }

            return _searchCommand;
        }
    }
```

**Bindings**

SelectedItem Binding

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,5,10,10" ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" Name="UsersDataGrid" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUser, Mode=TwoWay}" >
```

Search Button Binding

```
<Button Command="{Binding SearchCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=SearchBox, Path=Text}" Content ="Search" Width="50"></Button>
```

This is a MVVM approach meaning that i can not directly access the Datagrid.

Edit 1: Added selectedUser Just for completeness.

```
public UserDetailsModel SelectedUser
    {
        get { return _selectedUser; }

        set
        {
            _selectedUser = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedUser));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does `SelectedUser` raise the `PropertyChanged` event?

Comment: @Mikev this duplicate doesn't apply, it's not even about WPF. DIrect manipulation of UI elements should be avoided, especially when MVVM is used. The OP correctly binds the `SelectedItem` property here.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes it does. The Selected Item does update correctly, it's just the focus which does not get updated.

Comment: Can u share your `User` class?

Comment: If I remember correctly, there is an IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem property in DataGrid, can you try it?

Comment: @babgev as far as i'm aware this property is mainly used when connecting two different collections to the same item source for example two list views. This makes sure that they are both selecting the same Item. Unfortunately this property does not alter the current focus of the datagrid. Thank you though

Comment: I would always prefer to use a CollectionView to get or manipulate the selected item. Therefore you must set the IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem to true in XAML and get the the CollectionView from CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultCollectionView within the VM. You do not need a property for the selectedItem anymore.

Comment: Have a look at this one => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18019425/scrollintoview-for-wpf-datagrid-mvvm/43425033