# WPF DataGrid ScrollIntoView and Focus row/cell problem

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, focus

I am facing very similar issue as the question [ScrollIntoView for WPF DataGrid (MVVM)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18019425/3096657). Same as the linked question, I would make the DataGrid scroll to the selection, whenever `SelectedItem` changes, on top of that I would like to **move focus** there as well.
The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18028873/3096657) provides a solution for keeping `SelectedItem` in view using shadow `SelectingItem` attached property:

```
// 'SelectingItem' attached property changed callback
static void OnSelectingItemChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var grid = sender as DataGrid;
    if (grid == null || grid.SelectedItem == null) return;

    grid.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => 
    {
        grid.UpdateLayout();
        grid.ScrollIntoView(grid.SelectedItem, null);
        FocusSelectedRow(grid); // to be implemented
    });
}
```

How can I also focus the newly selected row/column? A strightforward solution calling `cell.Focus()` fails of `DataGridTemplateColumn` columns:

```
static void FocusSelectedRow(DataGrid dg) 
{
    if (dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(dg.SelectedItem) is DataGridRow row)
    {
        row.ApplyTemplate();
        var presenter = row.GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>();

        if (presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column?.DisplayIndex ?? 0) is DataGridCell cell)
        {
            cell.Focus(); // does not work properly for DataGridTemplateColumns!
        }
    }
}
```

with the solution above, the cell is correctly focused only for non-`DataTemplate` columns it messes up GUI interaction. For `DataTemplate` columns it creates feedback loop - when a cell in such column is clicked, it also changes `SelectedItem`. Which in turn triggers the callback, and the `cell.Focus()` swallows original event, making any input elements (e.g. `Button`) uninteracitble (until *second* click). How can I fix this select-focus problem?

Comment: Who is changing selection? User? You don't want to steal focus from user.

Comment: @Sinatr It might not be the brighetest UX idea, but the users explicitly requested it as a requirement because they are used to same behaviour in legacy system. Plus it makes sence in some parts (e.g. 'Reload' keybinding returns focus where it was before, or 'Jump to' keybinding updates focus correctly), but agree in other parts it does not make that much sense.

Comment: Second click could indicate there is a focusable container inside cell. Check datatemple and who has focus after `cell.Focus()`. I don't have much experience with `DataGrid`, but it could be also dispatcher issue, try to invoke `cell.Focus()` via dispatcher.

Comment: @Sinatr updated the last paragraph to be more accurate what is happening. From VM it works, but from GUI it creates feedback loop - when you click a row, it changes data-bound SelectedItem, which triggers the callback, where during `cell.Focus()` the original click event gets hijacked/rerouted into void. Tested it with and without dispatcher, no change. Right now I am looking into how to break the loop.